# Normality tests for dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, normal-distribution

I'm doing some normality tests for two columns of two dataframes:

```
# Normality tests

shapiro.test(male$height)
shapiro.test(female$height)

ad.test(male$height)
ad.test(female$height)

cvm.test(male$height)
cvm.test(female$height)

lillie.test(male$height)
lillie.test(female$height)

pearson.test(male$height)
pearson.test(female$height)

sf.test(male$height)
sf.test(female$height)
```

But this looks very inefficient to me. I tried using tapply and apply functions but I couldn't make it work. Any guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with `lapply`:

```
lapply(list(male, female), function(x) {

 list(shapiro.test(x$height),
      ad.test(x$height),
      cvm.test(x$height),
      lillie.test(x$height),
      pearson.test(x$height),
      sf.test(x$height))

})
```

Comment: Just as I wanted. Is there any way to change the text of the output  `[[1]]
## [[1]][[1]]`  that is been displayed before the results of the test? (Just curiosity)

Comment: If I understand correctly what you mean you may want to change the inner `list` to `c`.